# cURL blocking with CDATA

Tags: php, xml, curl, cdata

G'Day everyone !

This is not another CDATA question with a LIBXML_NOCDATA, I actually have a problem at the source of my cURL (multi) requests. If the XML sent back by the API contains a CDATA then the curl stops and nothing is retrieved from the CDATA to the end. It does mean that the LIBXML_NOCDATA is useless as there are no CDATA in the retrieved result.

```
        $endpoint = 'http://theapiservice.com?sentence=';

        $urls = array();
        foreach( $sentences as $key => $value ) {
            $urls[] = $endpoint . $value;
        }

        $multi = curl_multi_init();
        $channels = array();
        $results = array();

        // Loop through the URLs, create curl-handles
        // and attach the handles to our multi-request
        foreach ( $urls as $url ) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

            curl_multi_add_handle( $multi, $ch );

            $channels[$url] = $ch;
        }

        // While we're still active, execute curl
        $active = null;
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec( $multi, $active );
        } while ( $mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM );

        while ( $active && $mrc == CURLM_OK ) {
            // Wait for activity on any curl-connection
            if ( curl_multi_select( $multi ) == -1 ) {
                continue;
            }

            // Continue to exec until curl is ready to
            // give us more data
            do {
                $mrc = curl_multi_exec( $multi, $active );
            } while ( $mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM );
        }

        // Loop through the channels and retrieve the received
        // content, then remove the handle from the multi-handle
        foreach ( $channels as $channel ) {
            $results[] = curl_multi_getcontent( $channel );
            curl_multi_remove_handle( $multi, $channel );
        }

        // Close the multi-handle and return our results
        curl_multi_close( $multi );
```

And here is the XML from the API that should be retrieved. There is a CDATA which means I will only get what is before, and not after. And this is the only part where there are line breaks too.

```
<Word>
    <Surface>DATA1</Surface>
    <Sub>DATA1_Sub</Sub>
</Word>
<Word>
    <Surface>）</Surface>
</Word>
<Word>
    <Surface>
    <![CDATA[ ]]>
    </Surface>
</Word>
<Word>
    <Surface>DATA2</Surface>
    <Sub>DATA2_Sub</Sub>
</Word>
```

What I get (you can see that nothing is retrieved from CDATA):

```
[23] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Surface] => DATA1 [Sub] => DATA1_Sub ) [24] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Surface] => ） ) ) ) ) )
```

When the request is correct and no CDATA is sent back, then everything is perfect and I can parse the XML normally. Do you have any idea on how I should do to at least get 100% of the XML and not only the part before the CDATA?

Thank you